# Remove guid from image filenames in Piranha CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

Currently when image and other media files are uploaded to the media section of Piranha CMS, the filename has the guid prepended to the filename

Is there a way to upload image files (and other media files) without prepending the guid to the filename?

We would prefer to keep the original filename including when we use the WYSIWYG editor to add images to blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guid is used to ensure uniqueness of filenames and **can't** be removed by configuration. My suggestion is that you create a new issue for this over at GitHub, because it shouldn't be too much work to add a new Hook letting you override the default resource name generation.

Best regards